# Angular 14: ngx-masonry implementation issues

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, npm

I am using Angular 14 framework and the ngx-masonry library (https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-masonry/v/14.0.1), but I am experiencing issues with it not working properly. Could anyone provide assistance or advice on how to resolve this issue? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The output of this code is a blank screen.

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { NgxMasonryModule } from 'ngx-masonry';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { TitleComponent } from './title/title.component';
import { CdkScrollingComponent } from './cdk-scrolling/cdk-scrolling.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    TitleComponent,
    CdkScrollingComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    NgxMasonryModule,
  ],
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule {}
```

cdk-scrolling.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-cdk-scrolling',
  styleUrls: ['cdk-scrolling.component.css'],
  templateUrl: 'cdk-scrolling.component.html',
})

export class CdkScrollingComponent{

  masonryItems = [
      { title: '/assets/memes/meme1.jpg' },
      { title: '/assets/memes/meme2.jpg' },
      { title: '/assets/memes/meme3.jpg' },
      { title: '/assets/memes/meme4.jpg' },
      { title: '/assets/memes/meme5.jpg' },
      { title: '/assets/memes/meme6.jpg' },
      { title: '/assets/memes/meme7.jpg' },
      { title: '/assets/memes/meme8.jpg' },
      { title: '/assets/memes/meme9.jpg' },
      { title: '/assets/memes/meme10.jpg' },
      { title: '/assets/memes/meme11.jpg' },
      { title: '/assets/memes/meme12.jpg' },
      { title: '/assets/memes/meme13.jpg' },
      { title: '/assets/memes/meme14.jpg' },
      { title: '/assets/memes/meme15.jpg' },
    ];

    constructor() {}
}
```

cdk-scrolling.component.html

```
<ngx-masonry>
  <div ngxMasonryItem class="masonry-item" *ngFor="let item of masonryItems">
    {{item.title}}
  </div>
</ngx-masonry>
```

cdk-scrolling.component.css

```
.masonry-item { 
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Just a guess, but look at the page in the devtools - I suspect that the height of your div is zero. You'll probably have to specify a height in addition to the width for the masonry-item css class

Comment: F12 - look for errors in the console

Comment: @GreyBeardedGeek Thanks for the suggestion. I tried it out and the same result remains.

Comment: @user21057724 Unless there are error messages present, the question remains - when you inspect the DOM, are there divs there with the masonry-item css class, and if so, do they have an actual height and width? If they're there, but have zero height and/or width, then it's a css problem. If they're not there at all, then it's something else. Divide and conquer!

Comment: @GreyBeardedGeek You were right! The issue was with the height. Even after inputting it, it remained zero since I did not have the BrowserAnimationsModule imported (for reasons unknown still). I really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you might have a problem with the path of the images.

In your code, you are providing the path of the images as '/assets/memes/meme1.jpg', '/assets/memes/meme2.jpg', etc.
It seems like these images are located in the assets folder under the project root directory.

In that case, you need to make sure that the path of the images is correct and that the images are indeed present in that location.

Another possible issue could be that the images are not loading due to a problem with the CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) policy. The browser may block the images from loading if it detects that they are coming from a different origin than the one the app is being served from. You can check the browser's developer console for any error messages related to CORS.

You can also try to use the ng serve --prod command to see if the problem persists and if the problem is with the development server or not.

Also, you can try to change the path of the images to use relative path instead of absolute path like

{ title: 'assets/memes/meme1.jpg' }

It will help you to understand the problem is with the path of the images or anything else.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @hozefam. I've made sure my paths are correct and there seems to be no problem with the server. I believe it might be more of an syntax issue in the html and css code.